# Need to obtain HorizontalResolution and VerticalResolution in SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, skiasharp

I am trying to scale a picture by SkiaSharp and got the following code:

```cs
Stream pictureStream = GetPictureStream(filename);
using var skImageStream = new SKManagedStream(pictureStream);
using var skPicture = SKPicture.Deserialize(skImageStream);                                     
var width = skPicture.CullRect.Width / skPicture.HorizontalResolution * 72;
var height = skPicture.CullRect.Height / skPicture.VerticalResolution * 72;
```

I am looking for a way to obtain `HorizontalResolution` and `VerticalResolution` from skPicture or anything else in SkiaSharp but I failed to find a solution. `SKPicture`, `SKCanvas`, and `SKBitmap`, do not have such a property.

Could you please suggest a solution for this problem?

Comment: SKPicture is just a recording of drawing commands, it's not an image until drawn. And resolution is just a metadata of images to indicate print size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is per Maku's comment made above: SKPicture is just a recording of drawing commands, it's not an image until drawn. And resolution is just a metadata of images to indicate print size.